# php trying to upload file: "No Such file or directory"

Tags: php, upload

I want to upload a file into an existing folder, `/media/images/avatars/`, but receive the following error: `No such file or directory`. What am I doing wrong? I'm using Ubuntu, if that matters.

**Here is my code:**

```
if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name']))
{
    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
      || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
      || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
      || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
      && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 64000)
      && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            if (file_exists("/media/images/avatars/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
            {
                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
            else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                "/media/images/avatars/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            }
        }
        $ins['avatar'] = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid file";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that an absolute or a relative path? The first thing I would do for troubleshooting is make sure that you're using an absolute path.

Comment: It's located in var/www/aaa/media/images/avatars/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> /media/images/avatars/ is an existing folder

I am pretty sure you are wrong.
Most likely you are referring to a *web-server* directory, though using absolute path from the *filesystem* root.

So, you have to prepend your path with *document root* path, which you can find in the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` variable on a well-configured server

Comment: "I am pretty sure you are wrong." It turns out, I should have put media/images/avatars/. Without the first slash before media. It works now.